# jQuery is not overwriting text coming from php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php file coming from a global assets folder, in the footer I have this:

```
<?php
    include('../global/includes/footer_template.php');
?>
```

and in that template I have something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $legalUrl;?>"target="_blank">
   <?php echo ($isLangSpanish?'Nota Legal':'Legal Notices');?>
</a>
```

so in the view you will see 'Legal Notices', for one of the pages the client is asking me to uncapitalize the 'N' in Notices. So I did this with jQuery

```
<?php
    include('../global/includes/footer_template.php');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.footer p a').text().replace('Notices', 'notices');
    });
</script>
```

And it works in the browser console:

[image]

But I can't see that change in the view.

What can I do?

*NOTE:*
I can't change the footer template in the assets because it's been used for other projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the value back.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.footer p a').text($('.footer p a').text().replace('Notices', 'notices'));
});
```

a little cleaner:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var link = $('.footer p a'),
        updatedText = link.text().replace('Notices', 'notices');
    link.text(updatedText);
});
```

Comment: For reference, "[The replace()] method does not change the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

Posting an alternative solution using a callback to `text()`,

```
$('.footer p a').text(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace('Notices', 'notices')
});
```

---

*[.text( function )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)*

> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.